# Avoiding duplication in array

Tags: solidity, arrays

Here is my code :

> ```
> pragma solidity ^0.4.14;
>
>
> contract AdminSetUp {   // contract for adding new admin
> address private creator = msg.sender;
> address[] public adminlist;
> uint public count;
>
>
> modifier onlyCreator {  // only creator of contract is allowed to add admin
>     if (msg.sender == creator)
>     _;
> }
>
> function addMember(address _newadmin) public onlyCreator returns (uint) {
>     adminlist.push(_newadmin);
>     count = adminlist.length;
>     return count;
>  }
>
>
>
> }
> ```

this code allows to add admin those are already there. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through the array and make sure that the `_newadmin` != match any existing array entries.

Or

Possibly convert to use a `mapping(address -> bool) isAdmin` instead. Which would prevent having to iterate through the entire array. As a simple example below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

contract AdminSetUp is Ownable{
    
  struct Admin {
        uint adminData;
        bool isAdmin;
      }
    
  mapping (address => Admin) public admins;

  function isAdmin(address _address) public view returns(bool _isAdmin) {
    return admins[_address].isAdmin;
  }

  function newAdmin(address _address, uint _adminData) public onlyOwner returns(bool success) {
    // Make sure admin doesn't already exist and validate _address
    require(!isAdmin(_address) && _address != address(0));
    admins[_address].adminData = _adminData;
    admins[_address].isAdmin = true;
    return true;
  }

  function removeAdmin(address _address) public onlyOwner returns(bool success) {
    // Make sure admin exists and validate _address
    require(isAdmin(_address) && _address != address(0));
    admins[_address].isAdmin = false;
    return true;
  }

  function updateAdminData(address _address, uint _adminData) public onlyOwner returns(bool success) {
    require(isAdmin(_address));
    admins[_address].adminData = _adminData;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done a slightly different approach:

Admin Struct, with an Id and the address (you can add more things if you want)

```
struct Admin {
        uint256 adminId;
        address adminAddress;
    }
```

Here I'm mapping the Admin Struct in an Unordered list.

```
    address[] private adminIndex;
    mapping(address => Admin) mapping_admin;
```

Function to check if the admin is already registered.

```
function adminExist(address newAdmin) public view returns (bool adminExist) {
        if (adminIndex.length == 0)
            return false;

        return (adminIndex[mapping_admin[newAdmin].adminId] == newAddress);
    }
```

Function to register a admin with a validation.

Here, is where the magic happens, I'm matching the Array Index with the adminId.

```
    function addAdmin(address adminAddress) onlyCreator public returns (uint256) {
        require(adminAddress!= address(0));

        if (!adminExist(adminAddress)) {
            var newAdmin = Admin(adminIndex.length, adminAddress);

            mapping_admin[adminAddress] = newAdmin ;
            adminIndex.push(adminAddress);

            return newAdmin.adminId;
        }
    }
```